# Why Need to append newly created nodes in a tree to queue

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm creating a binary tree reading a list .As i traverse my list, 2k+1 element is my left child  and 2k+2 element in my array is my right child ( starting form 0th index in array).

Suppose i have array 10,20,30,40,50 then 10 is the root 20 is left child 30 is right child for root 10.Similary for root.left i.e 20 it will have two child 40 ,50 based on the formula i mentioned.
As we traverse the array a new node is created either for a root,left child or right The newly created object gets appended to queue.

```
class createnode:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.root=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

class createbinarytree:

    def array(self):
        self.q=[]
        self.num=int(raw_input("enter the number of element you want in the list"))
        for i in range(0,self.num):   
          self.num1=int(raw_input("enter the " + `i+1` +"element"))
          self.q.append(self.num1)

    def createtree(self):
        z=[]
        arr_len=len(self.q)
        k=0
        root_data=self.q[0]
        self.top=createnode(root_data)  
        z.append(self.top)  #Why we appened to list?

        while(k<arr_len):

           self.parent=z.pop(0) #poped value will be used as to refer to left or right child
           self.x=int(2) * int(k)+int(1)
           if(self.x>=arr_len):
             break;  
           left_data=self.q[self.x]
           self.left_child=createnode(left_data)
           z.append(self.left_child)
           self.y=int(2) * int(k)+int(2)
           if(self.y>=arr_len):
             break;  
           right_data=self.q[self.y]
           self.right_child=createnode(right_data)
           z.append(self.left_child)
           self.parent.left=self.left_child  ##Here it is used why not self.top directly 
           self.parent.right=self.right_child         

           k=k+1
    def inordertraversse(self,top):
           if(top):
            self.inordertraversse(top.left)
            print(top.root)
            self.inordertraversse(top.right)

conv=createbinarytree();
conv.array()
conv.createtree()
print("the inorder traversal is ")
conv.inordertraversse(conv.top)
```

**Output : 14,11,15,10,13**

With the statement `z.append(self.top)`we appended  the newly created variable to the list .So why can't we use self.top directly in the further parts of the program.Like i tried with the below code   it only print me the latest root value,a single element.

```
class createnode:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.root=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

class createbinarytree:

    def createtree(self):
        self.l=[1,2,3,4,5]
        arr_len=len(self.l)
        k=0

        while(k<arr_len):
           root_data=self.l[k]
           self.top=createnode(root_data)
           self.x=int(2) * int(k)+int(1)
           if(self.x>=arr_len):
             break;  
           left_data=self.l[self.x]
           self.left_child=createnode(left_data)

           self.y=int(2) * int(k)+int(2)
           if(self.y>=arr_len):
             break;  
           right_data=self.l[self.y]
           self.right_child=createnode(right_data)
           self.top.left=self.left_child
           self.top.right=self.right_child
           print(self.top.left.root)
           print(self.top.right.root)
           k=k+1
    def inordertraversse(self,top):
           if(top):
            self.inordertraversse(top.left)
            print(top.root)
            self.inordertraversse(top.right)

conv=createbinarytree();
conv.createtree()
print("THe inorder traversal")
conv.inordertraversse(conv.top)
```

**Output: 3**

Why we see such behavior ?Do we need to store the newly created objects in data structures like list etc  everytime in case if we want to refer the objects further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your (2nd) code block, look at this line when it is executed after some iterations have already been completed:

```
self.top=createnode(root_data)
```

and then ask yourself how this node can become the child of another node you have already created previously. The only other thing you do with `self.top` is to assign its children. But `self.top` itself remains an orphan. Also, it will never have grandchildren, since the children are never referenced again in any of the next iterations.

That is why there is a list in the first version of your code which is used as a queue (first in, first out): it allows to link up new nodes to their parent node that you have kept in the queue. Because of the well-defined order in the array representation of the tree, the current node's parent is always the node that is next pulled from the queue. You would not know which was the parent if you did not have that queue.

Still there is a problem in that code when the tree is not full. Try with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and you will see the output only lists 5 nodes (because of a `left_child` instead of `right_child` bug) or 7 (when that bug is fixed).

This is because you break out of the loop when a node does not have a child, but you should not end the loop before all nodes have been added to the tree.

So don't do this:

```
if(self.x>=arr_len):
    break;
```

Instead test the inverse condition, and if true perform the related actions, but still continue the loop.

As a side note, don't use `self` properties unless you want to expose that data. But in your code, I would not use `self.x`, `self.parent`, ... etc, since they are just used for temporary storage. Instead remove the `self.` prefix so they are local, private names.

Also, you don't need to wrap with parentheses in `if` or `while` conditions.

The `int()` calls are unnecessary: all those values are already integers.

So your while loop would look like this:

```
while k<arr_len:
    parent=z.pop(0)
    x=2*k+1
    if x<arr_len:
        left_data=self.q[x]
        left_child=createnode(left_data)
        z.append(left_child)
        parent.left=left_child
    y=2*k+1
    if y<arr_len:
        right_data=self.q[y]
        right_child=createnode(right_data)
        z.append(right_child)
        parent.right=right_child         
    k=k+1
```

Be aware that you had `z.append(self.left_child)` twice: one of them had to be `z.append(self.right_child)`.

I would also suggest you provide your classes with constructors, so you can pass arguments when creating objects from them.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer .Putting  a z.append(self.left_child) while appending the right child  was causing the  printing of 5 out of those 7 elements 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 .The condition **if(self.x>=arr_len) ** is not causing any threats .I made the changes in the code as instructed  and it ran fine. @trincot

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] it works, but add one more value and it will still list only 7. I gave the wrong example, but you do need to avoid those `break` statements here.

Comment: Got it!!  NIce Catch @trincot